# check if a interpolated method call is undefined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, string-interpolation

I have an interpolated method call, `send("#{k}_track", k, v)`.
I would like to run a check to see if the method that is being called is defined or not.

Something along the lines of `next if send("#{k}_track", k, v) == undefined`.
The method that is being called is just a standalone method in a service.

I've tried using `try` or `method_defined?` but not luck. They just return the same undefined method error.
So i'm not sure if this is even possible.

Comment: _"I've tried using try or method_defined? ..."_ – can you show your attempts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Object#respond_to?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Object.html#method-i-respond_to-3F):

```
send("#{k}_track", k, v) if respond_to?("#{k}_track")
```

Or in the case with next:

```
next unless respond_to?("#{k}_track")
send("#{k}_track", k, v)
```

Answer (score 1):

You might need [`respond_to?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-respond_to-3F) instead of [`method_defined?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-method_defined-3F). This depends on if you're checking for an instance or class method. For example, let's look at String and it's `upcase` method.

```
"foo".respond_to?("upcase")
=> true
```

This means you can call `upcase` on `"foo"`, e.g. `"foo".upcase`.

```
String.method_defined?("upcase")
=> true
```

This is roughly the same informing you that instances of String respond to `upcase`.

Now, let's look what happens when we try to call `method_defined?` on an instance:

```
"".method_defined?("upcase")
NoMethodError (undefined method `method_defined?' for "":String)
```

This makes sense because `method_defined?` exists on String but *not* an on instance of String.

It's difficult to tell without more context but to wrap this up, I think in your case you might want to be using `respond_to?` and the error you were seeing was for calling `method_defined?` on an instance.

Comment: Using `respond_to?` and duck typing is far more commonly used then `method_defined?` which is really mainly for meta-programming.